# Prove that for all $x \in R$, the ideal $xR$ is proper.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring without identity. Suppose $R$ doesn't contain a proper maximal
ideal, and $R$ is not the zero ring. Prove that $\forall x \in R$, the ideal $xR$ is proper.

Comment: There is one very obvious approach to try; can you see what it is? Suppose that there is ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I tried construct an element in $R$ that is not in $xR$. Say let $A_1 \subsetneq A_2 \subsetneq \dots$ be an infinite chain of ideals. I was thinking of picking an element in each ideal and saying something about it, but cannot so far. I'm also wondering in general if $I$ is an ideal and $rI = I$ for every $r \in R$, what can we say about $I$? Then use this to compare $xA_i$ with $A_i$

Comment: The hypothesis that $R$ has no proper maximal ideal seems to be superfluous, and it’s pointed you in the wrong direction. The fact that $R$ has no identity is the one on which you should focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $xR=R$. There is some $y\in R$ such that $xy=x$. Now let $r\in R$ be arbitrary. Then $r=xz$ for some $z\in R$, so $r=xyz=\ldots\;$?

Comment: so $r = xyz = yxz = yr = ry$ for every $r \in R$, thus $y$ is the identity. Contradiction.

Comment: @algor207: Yep; looks good!